# How can I add two images on two separate image views with two different buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I add two images on two separate image views with two different buttons?

I used the below code for cropping and setting the image, for just a single button and single image view.

So what should I do for the two separate image views with two separate buttons on single screen?

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        CropImage();
    else if(requestCode == 2)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            uri = data.getData();
            CropImage();
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHead);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}


private void CropImage() {

    try{
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");

        CropIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX",180);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY",180);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX",3);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY",3);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded",true);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);

        startActivityForResult(CropIntent,1);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {

    }

}


 private void GalleryOpen() {
    GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent,"Select Image from Gallery"),2);

}
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I removed the image link as it seemed to just be a screenshot of a portion of the code you included. If that's incorrect, please [edit] in the relevant code as text, *not* an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a global boolean variable buttonOne and set it to a default value of false. Now, if buttonOne is clicked, set `buttonOne =True`. After that, in your `onActivityResult()` method, add another conditional statement

```
if (buttonOne){
imageViewOne.setImage();
}
else if(!buttonOne){
  imageViewTwo.setImage();
}
```

I hope this will work, if I understood your problem correctly.